# How to attach a file when creating a meeting invitation on Teams using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, botframework

I'd like to attach a file when I create a meeting invitation using Graph API. I want to create a meeting invitation from Azure Bot, send out the invitation to related members when an error is detected, and then attach the remote desktop connection file to the email.

Could you please tell me how to attach the file, how to arrange and reference the file resources?

How to attach a file when creating a meeting invitation using Graph API

Comment: Could you please try using [Create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API? The event object supplied in the request body has an [attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#methods) property.You can then [Add attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to the event.